# Adding Bluetooth device with a known link key to a Windows 7 system

Tags: windows, security, bluetooth

Assuming the device still considers itself paired with the computer, is it possible to configure it in Windows programatically when the link key is known?

I see Windows CE has `BthSetLinkKey` and `SO_BTH_SET_LINK`, but no such thing seems to be available on Windows.